# Expanding bullets on link hover

Tags: css, hyperlink, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a link that expands pseudo-element *before* on hover.

```css
.open-link::before {
      content: '•';
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10px;
      transition: width .3s;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
.open-link:hover::before {
      content: '• • •';
      width: 30px;
 }
```

```html
<a class="open-link" href="#">Link</a>
```

But the transition is rather weird and it looks like the dots jump from the bottom. How to smooth it and make it look like they expand from the left?

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1u0tzxfg/

UPDATE

Here's a bit better transition:

```css
.open-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.open-link::before {
    content: '• • •';
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    margin-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.open-link:hover::before {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a class="open-link" href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: it's beacuse you set a width = 10px, ande the text goes out of the link

Comment: That's intentionally since if I set <width: 30px;> then <transition: width .3s;> will not work and transition won't be smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add: `white-space: nowrap;` to the *.open-link::before* tag.

```html
<style>
  .open-link::before {
    content: '•';
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    transition: width .3s;
    margin-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .open-link:hover::before {
    content: '• • •';
    width: 30px;
  }
</style>

<a class="open-link" href="#">Link</a>
```